# UITableViewController horizontal swipe pagination?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, xamarin.ios

I am trying to implement horizontal pagination in my UITableViewController. With each swipe a new set of items will be displayed in the UITableView.

So far I have tried doing this with a set of UITableViewControllers, a UIScrollView and a UIPageControl. This works however it has two issues.

1. It isn't efficient to load all of the UITableViewControllers in to memory at the start.
2. When swiping the UITableView still responds to the vertical swipe so it gives an unpleasant effect.

An app that does exactly what I want to do can be seen here https://itunes.apple.com/nz/app/nrl-live-scores-league-now/id382164737?mt=8

How can I implement a horizontal paged UITableView?

Comment: Why not use a UICollectionView with horizontal paging? Making each cell the same frame size as the full srceen?

Comment: Because each UITableView has more than one cell... There can be up to 20 cells in each

Comment: sorry for not clarifying - I meant add the UITableview as a subview on the content view within each collection view cell.  Then you can scroll up/down within tableview, and left/right between tableviews (inside collection view). Each tableview will be instantiated only when the cellForRowAtIndexPath is called, so need to hold reference to all of them.  You will need to hold a strong reference to each uitableview within each uicollectionviewcell however.

Answer (score 3):

I've recently done a very similar behavior using a `UIPageViewController` and `UITableViewController`'s for the content. That's very easy and straight forward to implement.

To give an example:

You need a `UIPageViewController` that implements the `UIPageViewControllerDataSource` protocol. The dataSource asks for the methods:

```
- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
  viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController;
```

and

```
- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:
                      (UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
   viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController;
```

where you just need to return the `UITableViewController` instances which present your content.
The swiping etc. is a default behavior of `UIPageViewController`

For a more detailed example have a look at this [tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/uipageviewcontroller-storyboard-tutorial/) which helped me a lot.